# Как сделать срез картинки в css?

Tags: css

Добрый день. Есть вот такая PSD=шка. Как сделать срез внизу  и вверху?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 21%, 100% 0, 100% 86%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 21%, 100% 0, 100% 86%, 0% 100%);
```

Проценты могут меняться. Удобно подгонять здесь: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/
Но насколько помню, может не работать в IE.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, проблема решена!

Comment: нет... проблема не решена ... плохая поддержка у браузеров ...: https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path